# WebLogic OpenJDK 7 compatibility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

What versions of WebLogic application server are compatible with OpenJDK 7? I can't find any concise answer by Googling Oracle's documentation. Although there is a [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e14142/jdk7.htm) to getting Oracle's binary release of JDK 7 working, I don't know if this extends to OpenJDK.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the OpenJDK is officially supported at all by Oracle when it comes to using it with WebLogic. When trying the WebLogic generic installer `fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls.jar` together with OpenJDK 7 the installer will abort with the following error message:

```
2016-08-10 14:47:49,540 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - The OpenJDK JVM is not supported on this platform.
```

I have tried this using Alpine Linux 3.4. When using the Oracle JDK 7 the installation of the WebLogic server succeeds.

Comment: Same issue! The installation just won't proceed with OpenJDK JVM.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server):

```
Standard | WLS 7.0 | WLS 8.1 | WLS 9.0 | WLS 10.0 |     WLS 10.3     | WLS 12c
==============================================================================
Java     | 1.3     | 1.4     | 5       | 5        | 6 (7 in 10.3.6+) | 7
Java EE  | 1.3     | 1.3     | 1.4     | 5        | 5                | 6
Servlet  | 1.2     | 2.3     | 2.4     | 2.5      | 2.5              | 3.0
JSP      | 1.2     | 1.2     | 2.0     | 2.1      | 2.1              | 2.2
EJB      | 2.0     | 2.0     | 2.1     | 3.0      | 3.0              | 3.1
JDBC     | 2.0     | 2.0     | 3.0     | 3.0      | 3.0              | 4.0
```

Comment: Doesn't specify OpenJDK vs. Oracle's binary distributions, though.

Comment: this does not help with the question, as Oracle doesn't have support for OpenJDK in weblogic, which was the thing asked.